# Why Bootstrap class of Apache tomcat calls ClassLoader.loadclass instead of new operator?

Tags: java, apache, object, tomcat, classloader

I was going through apache tomcat opensource code, and at the start, in Bootstrap.java i found this:

```
Class<?> startupClass = catalinaLoader.loadClass("org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina");
```

even when Bootstrap.java and this Catalina.java belongs to the same package, Why Bootstrap(org.apache.catalina.startup) class of apache tomcat calls ClassLoader.loadclass to load Catalina class(org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina) and then class.newInstance, why not it just create Catalina instance using new operator?

Comment: Do you understand how classloading and different classloaders work?

Comment: I know little bit but will like to hear more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code uses explicitly `catalinaLoader` and assuming it later creates an instance of the class, it's to make sure that the `Catalina` class is loaded with a different classloader than the `Bootstrap` class.

For further information what this means, refer to documentation about class loading.

Comment: That's what my question is 'why it is required for tomcat to load Catalina class by different class loader than the Bootstrap class'?

Comment: That's too broad to answer here, but basically using your own classloader you have a lot more control over the classes being loaded *or* unloaded. Class loading is a complex subject, so if you are looking for more information you should be asking Google.